# Is wavefunction collapse “global”?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, measurements, observers, wavefunction-collapse

I have the feeling that the premises of this question may not be coherent (so to speak), but here goes:

Suppose we have a system $X$ in a quantum superposition between states $0$ and $1$, say, with equal amplitudes. Suppose we have two observers, Alice and Bob, who have never interacted with each other in any way. Alice measures $X$ to be $0$. Then, later, Bob measures $X$.

Will Bob “always” measure $X = 0$ if he never interacts with Alice, or will the wavefunction not have collapsed for him yet? Or does their both having measured the same system mean that they've interacted in a way that ensures they'll observe the same thing?

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[|\text{Alice}_0,\text{Bob}_0,X=0> + |\text{Alice}_1,\text{Bob}_1,X=1>]$

Comment: @CountIblis, I guess you mean that it's the third option?

Comment: OK, so Bob will also measure $X = 0$, but he and Alice could never confirm that their measurements agree unless they interact. So assuming that they don't, then from Bob's perspective, since the outcome was random (for Alice), it's still valid for him to view the system in a superposition until he measures it. So the story from both their perspectives is still consistent with the story of the full Alice + Bob + $X$ system. Is that the idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, wave function collapse is global in the sense that you mean, though I would use the word "objective" instead of "global". The measurements that have been performed and their outcomes are an objective element of reality.

alanf's answer is correct but makes things more complicated than they need to be. NUU misunderstood the question (it isn't about spacelike separated measurements), and their answer says

> If B knows the outcome of A, he must use the 'collapsed' wave function. If he does *not*, he must use what he knows, i.e. the original state X.

which is very wrong. Alice's measurement has an objective effect, and Bob must incorporate that into his world model, or else he will make wrong predictions. If he knows the outcome of Alice's measurement, he must use the post-measurement collapsed state. If he knows what measurement she made but doesn't know the outcome, he must use the post-measurement [mixed state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state#Mixed_states) (or model her as part of the system, as in alanf's answer, which amounts to the same thing). If he doesn't know what Alice did, he doesn't know the state and can't reliably make predictions.

There are various nits you could pick with this, so I want to clarify that measurements are objective in the same way that anything in a classical theory is objective. If your model of the present state of the universe is wrong about the Andromeda galaxy, your predictions about Earth will be right for the next 2.5 million years, and even after that they will probably be pretty close. Nevertheless, your starting state was wrong—just not wrong in a way that affected the predictions you made. In the same way, if you don't incorporate Alice's measurement into your model of the world, your model is objectively wrong, though still fine for many purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Wave function collapse is not global, it is fictional. Let's suppose that the state is $\alpha|X=0\rangle+\beta|X=1\rangle$, where $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1.$

When Alice measures the state, an operation is applied that correlates both Alice and the environment with the value of $X$, like so $|X=j\rangle|0\rangle_A|0\rangle_E|0\rangle_B\to|X=j\rangle|j\rangle_A|j\rangle_E|0\rangle_B$. The environment is just everything around the system other than Alice. The $A,E,B$ subscripts stand for Alice, the environment and Bob respectively.

Bob might get the measurement result directly from the system, or from Alice or the environment. In any case, the end result will be
$$\alpha|X=0\rangle|0\rangle_A|0\rangle_E|0\rangle_B+\beta|X=1\rangle|1\rangle_A|1\rangle_E|1\rangle_B.$$
After the measurement there are two versions of Bob: one version sees 0, the other sees 1. There is no version of Bob that sees both outcomes or some weird mix of 0 and 1, and there is a large literature that explains why this is the case, for an example see

http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0703160.

The short version is that only information contained in the eigenvalues of some observable, or a subset of such information, can be copied from one system to another. Bob won't see any other information because none of the rest of the information will be copied to him. This follows from quantum mechanics with no collapse postulate. So the collapse postulate is unnecessary for explaining that result.

Comment: All mathematical models are fictional. Some mathematical models correctly capture the outcome of experiments. Your answer expresses a preference. The universe doesn't care which model you prefer.

Comment: @JohnDoty An experiment is a set of events set up so that some measurable outcomes wouldn't be explained by the theory being tested. If you have no account of what a theory claims about reality, then you can't say whether the experiment has been set up correctly so whether or not quantum theory is true, having no account of what it is claiming about reality is a problem. Another problem: a mathematical model has terms that have physical implications and if you deny those implications then you're being inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I understand your question:

A and B are space-like separated and make a measurement on a *single* particle that has equal (or just non-vanishing) probabilities of being in A's or B's region.

You now ponder how the measurement process works on a deeper level.
Could the collapse be a dynamical (i.e. time dependent) process? I think it can *not*. If it were, A and B would both try to 'pull' the wave-function to their side. You also get in trouble with relativity and the question who starts the process first.Thinking deeper, this will probably lead to the conclusion that the wave-function is not to be considered as 'real' (or 'ontic'). But I have not done this or seen this done.

It is thus better to regard the wave-function just as information. As soon as A or B have measured the particle, they have gained information and can update (=collapse) the wave-function.

**Back to the specific question**: For the physical outcome, it does not matter *WHEN* you collapse the wave-function. QM always assures that only one of A,B can measure the particle. Asking *'when'* the collapse 'occurs' is not a sensible question, because the collapse is not dynamic.

Added: If B knows the outcome of A, he must use the 'collapsed' wave function. If he does *not*, he must use what he knows, i.e. the original state X.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly, $X$ is accurately described by two wavefunctions: one from Alice's perspective, and one from Bob's. Each represents the information that Alice and Bob have about the state of $X$. When Alice makes a measurement, the outcome of Bob's future measurement is determined—but he doesn't know what it is, so his (uncollapsed) wavefunction is still an accurate description of $X$'s state until he makes a measurement himself. Is that right?

Comment: No! One wave-function containing the information. On new information (measurement) you must update it.(btw: nice icon)

Comment: OK, but now I'm confused—how can any information about Alice's measurement reach Bob if they haven't communicated? If Bob writes down the state of $X$, even after Alice has measured it, he must write down a superposition, right?

Comment: I added this to my answer. Don't worry, if you can't accept this. Einstein also failed to do so.

Comment: I like very much the idea about wave function collapse being an update of information from observers point of view. That is very sound and has no magical interactions in it. In this picture, the 'collapse' means that observer can start simulating the system from the collapsed wave function and obtain match with the experiment.