Quantum entanglement from different frames of reference and the conservation laws
From my understand, if the wave function of a particle in entanglement collapses by being observed, the other particle's wave function also collapse immediately.
My questions are:

Is it possible to find a frame of reference where the collapse of the wave functions does not occur simultaneously.
If there is such frame, does it mean the conservation laws (energy, momentum, spin...) are temporarily violated (during the time different of the two collapses)?


As the question is not clear, let me make an example.
A Higgs boson at rest in the lab frame decay into an electron and a positron. As the spin of the Higgs boson is $0$, thus the sum of the spin of the beta particles from the decay must also be $0$.
In the lab frame, a physicist measures the spin on the X direction of the electron and get the value $1/2$. Due to the measurement, the electron spin is no longer in superposition (and we say that its wave function collapse).
As spin conserves, the spin of the positron is also determined immediately, and thus its spin state is also reduce.
In the lab frame, the collapse of the wave functions, or the reduction of the states of the beta particle occur at the same time at two different places. That what Einstein called "spooky action at a distance", but we will not discuss it here.
The question arises when we change to a frame moving at a constant velocity to the lab frame. Due to the Lorentz transformation, the observer in this new frame will see the reduction of the states occur at different times. So he come to a conclusion that spin is not conserved momentarily.
Can we tell if the new observer right or wrong, or we don't have a good answer?

Observation has nothing to do with it and wavefunctions/entanglement is only mathematical. It has nothing to do with what's physically happening in real time.

It's important to note that the comment above does not represent a consensus view within the research community on quantum interpretations.

What do  "the wave function of a particle in entanglement" and "the other particle's wave function" mean?

In entanglement the wavefunction is a function of both positions. The state is entangled precisely because it cannot be separated into two individual ones. The wavefunction is not a physical object in spacetime. It is a function of both position vectors. It represents and encodes the observer's knowledge, i.e. what reality is to the observer.

@VincentThacker even if we define that the wave function is just a mathematical description, the reduction of the state occurs at two "points" in space and thus can be considered as two events.

Relevant answers to similar questions
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/622155/does-the-collapse-of-the-wave-function-happen-immediately-everywhere/740927#740927
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/255175/is-wavefunction-collapse-global/255620#255620

See the papers by Peres, Peres and Terno about quantum information in relativistic quantum mechanics and classical interventions. Your question is somewhat ill-defined to me, because it seems to rely on "wave function collapse", whose ontological status is not clear (same for wavefunction). Anyways, experimentally, there are two measurements, QM predicts their correlation; that's basically it. I don't understand what you say about conservation laws at all. All observers agree on the measurement outcomes! In the typical EPR-B set-up, this means everyone agrees that the total $S_z=0$ measured.

Your question cannot be answered precisely, because no one knows exactly what "collapse" is or how it works mechanically.  Some interpretations of QM deny that something labeled collapse even occurs (i.e. they say collapse is not physical, as @BillAslept mentions).  However, this much is known - assuming there is something called collapse:

Time of collapse has no bearing whatsoever.  If you want to say there is collapse at one place in spacetime X that occurs before it occurs in another spacetime location Y, that's fine.  But strictly speaking, there is no standard theoretical notion that something at X "causes" something to happen at Y (in the normal sense of the word "causes").

It is equally satisfactory to say Y's collapse causes X's earlier collapse, as strange as that sounds.  In fact, particles can be entangled after they are measured.  If that doesn't throw traditional notions of causality into question, I don't know what does.  That process is called Delayed Choice Entanglement Swapping.  See for example:


Experimental delayed-choice entanglement swapping

Keep in mind that no experimental test of entanglement has ever demonstrated anything relating to ordering of observation (collapse) as a factor.  If there is such an element, it is completely hidden to testing.  Note that the theoretical treatment of entanglement predictions does not give any preference to ordering, as only the final measurement context is a factor.

Consequently, in consideration of the above: It should be clear that reference frame plays absolutely no known role in the experimental predictions or outcomes.  Any statement otherwise is simply an assumption with no observational or theoretical basis.

And finally: no conservation laws appear to be violated in entanglement tests.  There are some interpretations in which that might occur, and there have been proposals to transmit energy using entanglement.  However, nothing concrete is evident at this point giving any indication that conservation of anything might be violated.


I hope this helps.

when I said violation, I mean while a particle has its spin, for example, observed, the other one is still in superposition, thus spin conservation is violated. I'll update my question to make it clearer.

@Rekkhan Fair enough. However, you immediately run afoul of a common quantum mechanical miscue - reasonable as it might be. That being: trying to deduce what is occurring between measurements. (Peres: "unperformed measurements have no results:.) QM says the final measured result will not violate a conservation rule. You must consider the final full measurement context. There are many quantum scenarios in which "logical deductive reasoning" falls apart, and this is one. (Hopefully you would agree that reference frame cannot be a factor.)

A question if you don't mind. From my understanding, the states of the entangled particles are "glued" together, thus measuring one means measuring both, am I really deducing something without measuring? (to be honest, I don't know if we can do any other measurement in this case)

@Rekkhan By classical logic, you may correctly deduce the outcome of a measurement on B after learning the outcome on A. Experiment will confirm. But that is only true for a very specific measurement basis for both: that being both on the same basis. That's a special case! The general prediction is actually a function of both the basis of A and the basis for B. That's called the context, which is a combination of the future basis for A and B. Time and ordering is not a factor at all in that function. This nuance is not obvious, as we learned from the EPR (1935) & Bell (1964) papers

I definitely don't understand your last message starting from the 3rd sentence. I'm not a theorist so your explanation is quite abstract for me. May I ask what is the basis you are mentioning?

@Rekkhan Sorry about that, I can explain. I use basis and measurement basis interchangeably. When you measure polarization at some angle, that is a basis. So 0, 30, 45, 90 degrees are all bases. Also momentum and position have a basis. If you measure both entangled particles at 30 degrees, the value you get for one will allow you to predict the other with certainty. That fits with your idea. But that doesn’t apply in all cases, such as when you measure one on the 30 degree basis and the other on the 150 degree basis. This is a measurement context in which classical ideas start to break down.

The answer to your question depends on what is happening in reality to bring about the outcomes of quantum experiments.
One common view of quantum theory is that you should use the equations of quantum theory to make calculations but ignore any implications they might have for how the world works. Since you can't say that an experiment is set up correctly unless there is an explanation of what is happening in reality when it's set up correctly this is a non-starter.
There are alternatives to quantum theory that modify the equations of motion so that there is a physical process that selects only one outcome:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.14969
These theories have problems with reproducing well tested predictions of relativistic quantum theories so I won't consider them further:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568
The equations of motion of quantum theory without such modifications do not include collapse. In quantum theory a measurement is just an interaction that produces a record of some observable that can be copied. These interactions suppress interference between different values of the observables but don't eliminate the other values: this ic called decoherence. Macroscopic objects undergo such interactions on a scale of space and time that is small compared the scale of its evolution so we don't see interference in everyday life:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0306072
On this scale reality looks approximately like a collection of non-interacting universes as described by classical physics:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033
This is commonly called the many worlds interpretation but it is just an implication of unmodified quantum theory.
There are relativistic quantum field theories that are used to explain what is happening to quantum systems when the effects of relativity are significant. Those theories are Lorentz invariant and so their predictions don't depend on reference frames. Decoherence theory suppresses states in which conserved quantities aren't conserved so there is no problem with conservation laws:
https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.1802
Entanglement correlations arise as a result of locally inaccessible information in decoherent channels and the correlations only arise when the results of measurements are compared: there is no spooky action at a distance:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007
https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223
The observer would know that his relative state has changed but this can be understood as an entirely local process:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.02328
So the observer wouldn't see and wouldn't expect to see violations of conservation laws.
